# Зависимые контролы TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Привет всем. Поскажите пожалуйста, у меня страница, к которой привязан соответствующий VM со свойствами Width, Height и Depth. Эти свойства привязаны к 3-ем контролам TextBox. Все эти 3 свойства зависимы между собой: если изменяю одно, изменяются остальные два.
Как мне привязать их так к контролам TextBox, чтобы при процессе ввода текста в какой-либо, обновлялся текст в двух других. Суть в том, что у меня двусвязная привязка свойств к контролам, но обновление этих контролов происходит только после валидации, тоесть когда оно потеряет фокус. А мне нужно, чтобы после каждого введенного/удаленного символа из TextBox происходило обновление.

Естественно, хотелось бы услышать в рамках MVVM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установите в привязке `UpdateSourceTrigger` в значение `PropertyChanged`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}/>
```

Возможные значения перечислены здесь: [Перечисление UpdateSourceTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло:)

Answer (score 1):

Если вы пользуетесь MVVM, то *контролы должны лишь отражать состояние VM*. Это значит, что не контролы должны быть привязаны друг к другу, а свойства VM.

А это уж делается очевидным, тривиальным образом.

```
class NameEditorVM : VM
{

    string firstName, surname, composedName;
    bool isUpdating = false;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get => firstName;
        set { if (Set(ref firstName, value) && !isUpdating) CalcComposedName(); }
    }

    public string Surname
    {
        get => surname;
        set { if (Set(ref surname, value) && !isUpdating) CalcComposedName(); }
    }

    public string ComposedName
    {
        get => composedName;
        set { if (Set(ref composedName, value) && !isUpdating) SplitComposedName(); }
    }

    void CalcComposedName()
    {
        isUpdating = true;
        ComposedName = FirstName + " " + Surname;
        isUpdating = false;
    }

    void SplitComposedName()
    {
        isUpdating = true;
        string[] parts = ComposedName.Split();
        FirstName = parts[0];
        Surname = string.Join(" ", parts.Skip(1));
        isUpdating = false;
    }
}
```

Ну и не забудьте, как верно указал в ответе @Андрей, указать в привязке `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`.

---

P. S.: 
Использован стандартный базовый класс:

```
class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value,
                         [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            return false;

        field = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: У меня так и сделано. Спасибо